# Why is one question closed whilst another migrated when both are similarly off-topic?

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons

Two recent questions, both off-topic, both programming related and both are of the style, "it doesn't work; what's wrong". Yet one was closed and the other migrated to SO.

- [specific div css properties **[migrated]**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/specific-div-css-properties)
- [i got mysql error on this statement i don't know why **[closed]**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34585/i-got-mysql-error-on-this-statement-i-dont-know-why)

Why were they not both migrated to SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only migrate things that we think Stack Overflow would want. If a question is going to be closed on Stack Overflow, then we aren't going to migrate it and then make the Stack Overflow mods close it. So we'll close it here instead.

I'm not sure exactly why that question was closed instead of migrated, but I'll ask about this on the moderator chat room, and I'll see what the other mods think about migrating it.

**Edit:** the reason was because it's very low quality (no real detail in the title, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, I admit it wasn't a great question, but neither was the other. In fact the one that was closed I thought could be answered more succinctly than the one that was migrated, but hey, no worries, I see what you're saying.